# google sheet requring apply button manually every time

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script, google-sheets-formula, google-sheets-api, spreadsheet

I need help with auto running a query without having to click apply every time. Every day I get new data from a source thats on google cloud. I run a COUNTIFS to give me a total number for that day. The next day i have a data script that grabs that formula and applies it to the new date added, however I have to click "apply" every single day. How can I have it calculate without me having to click apply every day?

Things i tried (all failed):

1. script SpreadsheetApp.flush();
2. file > settings > calculations> on change and every hour
3. adding +now()-now() to formula

[image: google sheet]

Comment: Can you provide a minimal reproducible sample of your sheet? So I can test my solution?

Comment: `How can I have it calculate without me having to click apply every day?` Apply is just a button, so it must be linked to a script./macro Please edit the question to include the script.

Comment: Are you looking for triggers? Look for time triggers/edit triggers?

Comment: Thank you @Tedinoz, using a macro worked and came up with this working solution:  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  spreadsheet.getRange('B2').activate();
  SpreadsheetApp.enableAllDataSourcesExecution();
  spreadsheet.refreshAllDataSources();

Answer (score 0):

Using @Tedinoz comment, using a macro worked by using the following solution:

```
var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
spreadsheet.getRange('B2').activate(); 
SpreadsheetApp.enableAllDataSourcesExecution(); 
spreadsheet.refreshAllDataSources();
```